# cv2 SIFT + Brute force matching not giving good results

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, sift

So I'm trying to overlay a thermal image with an rgb image using SIFT to match features and homography so that I can overlay them later on.  The code I have works with about 50% of the thermal/rgb sets I have but many sets, such as this one, give horrible results.  I think the homography is fine but doesn't work because the matches are way off.  I'll attach some code, any advice on how to tune this would be great as I've spent a long time already trying to get this working on my own. Thanks!

```
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(sigma=1.6, contrastThreshold=0.04,edgeThreshold = 15)

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(rgb, None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(thermal, None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)
good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.8 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

good = sorted(good, key=lambda x: x.distance)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(rgb, kp1, thermal, kp2, good, None, flags=2)
```

which gives the following
[image: SIFT features matches with brute force matcher]
Then I do homography with RANSAC on the found matches

```
    if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0, maxIters=1000)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h, w, c = rgb.shape
    pts = np.float32([[0, 0], [0, h - 1], [w - 1, h - 1], [w - 1, 0]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)

    thermal = cv2.polylines(thermal, [np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA) # draw lines around as a box
    draw_params = dict(matchColor=(0, 255, 0),  # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor=None,
                   matchesMask=matchesMask,  # draw only inliers
                   flags=2)

    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(rgb, kp1, thermal, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
```

resulting in this
[image: Post homography matching features]
Like I said, I think that this is failing because the BFMatcher is not finding correct matches but I am not sure why.  Again any and all help is very appreciated!  I've tried using an orb detector, converting the rgb image to grayscale, and pre-sclaing images to similar sizes and still get bad results.

Here is an example of a working rgb-thermal pair to demonstrate what I am trying to do.
[image: Here is an example of a working rgb-thermal pair]

Comment: You might want to try playing with the SIFT parameters. Also, using sharpening filters might help (eg. unsharpmask) but as @DanyAlejandro says your image consists of a lot of locally similar matches so you might want to add some more info (more importantly to the grayscale image)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your image is that it's so simple compared to natural images (no color, no major differences in texture, etc.), you cannot reliably use SIFT and other techniques made with normal photos in mind. Most of your wrong matches are actually good matches, since the matches look locally similar to each other (after obtaining the descriptor).

My suggestion is to look at alternatives that match images using structural information, or add information to the image (e.g. using a height rainbow colormap since your images can be seen as bumpmaps; using the distance transform + colormap might work too, or using both mentioned + edge detection as the 3 channels for a very weird but heterogeneous color image) and see if SIFT behaves differently.